# Magento 2.4.4 Price not show in english number for Arabic language

Tags: magento2, price, stoe-language

I have two store

1. English
2. Arabic

In Arabic stores,  product prices or other custom prices are shown in Arabic numbers instead of English numbers.

like

```
٥٠٫٠٠$
```

only the Product details page price shows correctly.

how we can show English numbers in both stores?

Answer (score 0):

Step:1 Create di.xml **{vendore_name}/{module_name}/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Directory\Model\Currency">
        <plugin name="currency_format" type="{vendore_name}\{module_name}\Model\Currency" />
    </type>       
</config>
```

Step:-2 Craete plugin file Currency.php
**{vendore_name}/{module_name}/Model/Currency.php**

```
<?php
namespace {vendore_name}\{module_name}\Model;

use Magento\Framework\Locale\CurrencyInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Locale\FormatInterface;
  
class Currency
{
    /**
     * @var FormatInterface
     */
    private $localeFormat;
    /**
     * @var CurrencyInterface
     */
    private $localeCurrency;

    /**
     * Currency constructor.
     *
     * @param FormatInterface $localeFormat
     * @param CurrencyInterface $localeCurrency
     */
    public function __construct(
        CurrencyInterface $localeCurrency,
        FormatInterface $localeFormat

    ) {

        $this->localeFormat = $localeFormat;
        $this->localeCurrency = $localeCurrency;
    }

    public function aroundFormatTxt(
        \Magento\Directory\Model\Currency $subject,
        callable $proceed,
        $price,
        $options = []
    ) {
        if (!is_numeric($price)) {
            $price = $this->localeFormat->getNumber($price);
        }

        $price = sprintf("%F", $price);

        return $this->localeCurrency->getCurrency($subject->getCode())->toCurrency($price, $options);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can see this file:-

vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Locale/Data/numberingSystems.xml

and change the first line to be as following:-

```
<numberingSystem id="arab" type="numeric" digits="0123456789"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing same issue before. We can resolve this translation issue by do changes in following two files:-

1] Create plugin for change currency position as following:

**registration.php**

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Trek_Repositionprice',
    __DIR__
);
```

**etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Trek_Repositionprice" setup_version="1.0.0">
    </module>
</config>
```

**etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Directory\Model\Currency">
        <plugin name="change_currency_position"
            type="Trek\Repositionprice\Plugin\ChangeCurrencyPosition"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**Plugin/ChangeCurrencyPosition.php**

```
<?php

namespace Trek\Repositionprice\Plugin;

class ChangeCurrencyPosition
{
    /**
     * Change currency position
     *
     * @param \Magento\Directory\Model\Currency $subject
     * @param float $price
     * @param array $options
     * @return array|array[]
     */
    public function beforeFormatTxt(
        \Magento\Directory\Model\Currency $subject,
        $price,
        $options = []
    ) {
        $options['position'] = 16; // 16 is for Right position, 8 is for Standard position and 32 is for Left position
        return [$price,$options];
    }
}
```

2] If still after create above plugin whole price coverted in wrong format then we need to override `price-utils.js` file as below:-

- Just copy `/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/web/js/price-utils.js` file into your custom theme directory for ex `app/design/frontend/Namespace/Themename/Magento_Catalog/web/js/price-utils.js`
- Here `window.LOCALE` condition which converts whole price into particular locale language

[image]

After removed `window.LOCALE`condition price translation working proper.

[image]

Hope it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you need to make pluggin for this class

```
Magento\Framework\Currency\Data\Currency
```

at this function

```
setLocale
```

and check if is it arabic make the country other

[image: [![code area][1]][1]